# Write GET parameters with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, url, url-rewriting

Simple question: Can I write GET parameters to the current document URL with JavaScript?

Say my URL is:

```
/search
```

Can I change it to:

```
/search?price_from=100
```

Without posting back the page?

I'm creating a single-page JavaScript application and the [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). I would like to let people search without reloading the page. I'd also like to let them link to results page URLs that use standard GET parameters.

Comment: Can you post any code you've tried? If you're using the History API, can't you just use pushstate?

Comment: It looks like I can, yes. For some reason I assumed I wouldn't be able to write question marks to the URL with pushstate. An incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method):

```
var getParameters = "?price_from=100"
history.pushState(null, null, document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + getParameters);
```

The History API isn't supported by older browsers though, if you need to support them you could use Mark's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can howver put it after the hash, like:

/search#price_from=100

and that won't reload the page/postback.

Comment: If you use a framework for building single page apps, it will make this a lot easier.  AngularJS has a beautiful mechanism for this.

Comment: Here is a brand new example of an AngularJS application. LendingTree just launched this site: https://www.lendingtree.com/loan-explorer it's built with angularjs.

Comment: I'm using Backbone.js, so I can just use `app.navigate()`.